# How to create a custom list iterator helper for handlebars in java

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.java

I am using Handlebars for java from : **https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java**
I have a list of CustomObject and a template file template.hbs. I'm able to iterate over this list by using handle bars **{{#each customList}}** block.

Now I want to iterate only through even indexed objects in my customList.

Server side :

```
handlebars.registerHelper("even", new Helper<List<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(List<?> list, Options options)
                throws IOException {
            if(list!=null && list.size()>1) {
                for(int index=0;index<list.size();index++) {
                    if((index+1) % 2 != 0) {
                        options.fn(list.remove(index));
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
```

part of Template.hbs:

```
{{#even customList}}
  {{customProperty1}}
{{/even}}
```

But this doesn't iterate my customList instead it just prints my list as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to use builtin pseudo vars, so you can accomplish what you ask without messing with custom helpers:

```
{{#customList}}
  {{#if @even}}
    {{customProperty1}}
  {{/if}}
{{/customList}}
```

Notice that its internal index starts at 0 (interpreted as even), if you need to invert that you can use #unless or @odd.

I also would like to point out the [NumberHelper](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/blob/master/handlebars-helpers/src/main/java/com/github/jknack/handlebars/helper/NumberHelper.java), which offers isEven, isOdd & stripes.

But if you really insist in writing your own custom helper to iterate over even-indexed elements of an Iterable, you're better off studying the source of [EachHelper](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/blob/master/handlebars/src/main/java/com/github/jknack/handlebars/helper/EachHelper.java), there you'll also find other pseudo vars.

Comment: Thanks for giving insights on the built in pseudo vars even and odd. It serves my purpose :)